# I cannot for the life of me figure out why this elif statement is not working

Tags: python, python-3.11

I have to use two user defined modules with their own user defined functions.
The modules and functions work but the statement calling the functions ig giving me trouble.

```
processing = True
while processing:
    distanceValue = int(input("please enter distance value: "))
    length = input("what is the unit of length (M or K): ")

    if length == "M" or "m":
        kilometers = convertToKilometers(distancValue)
        print(distanceValue, "miles is equal to", math.ceil(kilometers), "kilometers")

    elif length == "K" or "k":
        miles = convertToMiles(distanceValue)
        print(same as above except swap miles and kilometers)

    else:
        statement
```

when I run the program it will correctly calculate the miles but when I try "K" it still comes back with miles. I have checked my indentation multiple times, I am just stumped

[the outcome I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EetcG.png)

Comment: `if length == "M" or "m"` is always true. You may have meant `if length == "M" or length == "m"`

Comment: why is it still true if I am inputting k?

Comment: but please if you don't mind can you explain in as much detail as you can why that worked?

Comment: `if length == "M" or "m"` is treated as `if (length == "M") or ("m")`. Now `"m"` is interpreted as true. Read https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations for further information.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al

Comment: Alternatively, you could do `if length.upper() == 'M':`